# Can someone recommend a single-port IP-KVM?

Tags: windows, networking, remote-access, keyboard-video-mouse

I'm looking for a small rock solid device I can configure with a static IP or DHCP and ship somewhere where a moron can hook it up to a server and I can access the box.

Quality software with quick reliable response so that I can configure RAID etc without issue is important.

Thanks!

Comment: [No.](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/)

Comment: Your comment took less time and was less helpful then my question. There are prob 10 single port IP KVMs on the market and I have a short amount of time to know which ones to consider. This is very relivent for anyone who's running a data center. Plenty of people want to know what "the" ip kvm to get is.

Comment: We don't do shopping questions MathewC - and don't mod-alert a moderator either, he was right - terse but right.

Comment: Please forgive my shortness. We see so many shopping questions here that sometimes I get very sick and tired of linking them all to the relevant pages that state that we don't do shopping questions, because they become out of date incredibly quickly (hence, "too localised")

Answer (score 3):

I've become partial to Opengear's IP-KVM: http://opengear.com/product-kvm.html.

I have successfully done exactly what you are describing (configure it, ship it to customer, who may or may not be a moron, and access their stuff remotely). This one is also particularly nice because it supports things like dynamic DNS, can provide drive images via USB, and the serial port can be used to configure the device, dial a modem, or as pass-through.

Comment: With appologies to the admin that closed the topic.  Another option is Startech.com's SV1115IPEXT.  It lets you use VNC to get back to the device you have plugged into it.  We have it in between our console and the KVM in our rack. Works great and has saved me more than once when one of us left a USB drive plugged into a server and we needed to "press any key to continue..."